# Cannot change build platform from AnyCPU to x64 in VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio, configuration

I have a VS 2022 (v17.0.1, 64 bit) solution with multiple projects as shown below. I can select x64 as the platform for the solution  but only the Global project can have its platform changed to x64. I want to change the platform of all other projects to x64 but clicking on the Platform combo box for any other projects only gives Any CPU as an option. There are no <New...> or <Edit...> options shown except for the Global project.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To add or change configurations, use the "Configuration Manager" button at the top of that dialog. That dialog looks very similar, but you have the "New..." or "Edit..." entries.

Note that for C# projects, the setting is mostly irrelevant nowadays, as  code will anyway be compiled in AnyCPU mode.

Comment: New and Edit.. options appear  when clicking Configuration Manager as suggested by PMF but if I try to create x64 as a New  option in order to set the platforms for projects other than Global to x64, an error appears saying the platform already exists. I need to specify x64 as some the DLLs in the the project will not work on x86 platform

Comment: Are these C# projects or native (C, C++) dlls?

Comment: They are all  C# projects

Comment: I think you're confusing things here. That setting has basically no effect, it's just the name of a configuration set, so if you add one that's called x64, that doesn't really _do_ anything. Also, C# dlls are platform-independent, so the platform setting has no effect anyway. So if a certain library (or classes within it) don't work on a specific platform (e.g. because they use large memory blocks, or because they call into some native OS methods), it's better to throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException` right there rather than abusing the build system for something it is not designed for.

Comment: What is the difference between the project which I can set to x64 platform (Global)  and the others which I cannot? When I try to create an installer I get the error ERROR: File 'Interop.WMPLib.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86', which is why I want to set all project to target x64.

Comment: I can't tell you that without further information. Show the project file of the project that becomes your main application (the exe file)